# How to group the values of elements using cross-references defined by their attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to group elements from across multiple <div> blocks if they have unique ids and the cross-references created by the corresp atrributes. The elements may have a corresponding match or may not. If their is no match, the corresp atrribute contains the value with zero. The real context of such matching may occur when linking words of the translation with their corresponding words in the original text. The XML input sample looks as follows:

```
<DIV>
 <div id="fr">
  <seg id="fr_1"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en2">AA</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">BB</w>, <w id="fr3" corresp="#en1">CC</w>.</seg>
  <seg id="fr_2"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en1">DD</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">EE</w>?</seg>
  <seg id="fr_3"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en1">FF</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">GG</w><w id="fr3" corresp="#en2">HH</w></seg>
 </div>
 <div id="en">
  <seg id="en_1"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr3">AX</w><w id="en2" corresp="#fr1">BX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#fr2">CX</w></seg>
  <seg id="en_2"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr1">DX</w><w id="en2" corresp="#en0">EX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#en2">FX</w></seg> 
  <seg id="en_3"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr1">HX</w> <w id="en2" corresp="#en3">IX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#en2">JX</w>.</seg>
 </div>
</DIV>
```

If to follow the linking path via the corresp attributes, the output should look as follows:

```
<div>
 <ol>
   <li><w>AA</w> : <w>BX</w><br/> <w>BB</w> : <w>CX</w><br/> <w>CC</w> : <w>AX</w> <br/> </li>
   <li><w>DD</w> : <w>DX</w><br/> <w>EE</w> : <w>FX</w><br/> </li>
   <li><w>FF</w> : <w>HX</w><br/> <w>GG</w> : <w>JX</w><br/> <w>HH</w> : <w>IX</w><br/></li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up other elements, it is usually best to make use of a key. It looks like you want the id of **seg** to be taken into account when looking for the corresponding elements, in which case you would define your key like this:

```
<xsl:key name="corresp" match="w" use="concat(substring-after(../@id, '_'), '#', @id)" />
```

Then, assuming you were positioned on a **w** element, to look up the corresponding value, you would use the key like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('corresp', concat(substring-after(../@id, '_'), @corresp))" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="corresp" match="w" use="concat(substring-after(../@id, '_'), '#', @id)"/>

   <xsl:template match="div[@id='fr']">
      <ol>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ol>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="div[@id='en']"/>

   <xsl:template match="seg">
      <li>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="w"/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w">
      <w>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </w>
      <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
      <w>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('corresp', concat(substring-after(../@id, '_'), @corresp))"/>
      </w>
      <br/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<DIV>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <w>AA</w> : <w>BX</w><br/><w>BB</w> : <w>CX</w><br/><w>CC</w> : <w>AX</w><br/>
      </li>
      <li>
         <w>DD</w> : <w>DX</w><br/><w>EE</w> : <w>FX</w><br/>
      </li>
      <li>
         <w>FF</w> : <w>HX</w><br/><w>GG</w> : <w>JX</w><br/><w>HH</w> : <w>IX</w><br/>
      </li>
   </ol>
</DIV>
```

You mention in your question that "If their is no match, the corresp atrribute contains the value with zero", but haven't given an example of this. What you could do though, is store the above result in a variable, and then just have an **xsl:choose** to output a zero. Something like this, perhaps....

```
 <xsl:variable name="value" 
               select="key('corresp', concat(substring-after(../@id, '_'), @corresp))"/>
 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="string-length($value) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$value" /><xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Re my quote, I've simply explained the idea behind the ids whose value contains zero, just in case anyone would wonder why some <w> values do not have matches at all. Yet, could you expand on your suggestion of storing the result in a variable - what should be done?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to give an example.

Comment: Thanks for example. One more question, your template does not work well if one w element from the first div has more than one match in the second div. In that case your template finds no matches at all. E.g. I made changes in the 2nd seg of the 1st div as this: <seg id="fr_2"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en1">DD</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en2 #en3">EE</w>?</seg>

Comment: Btw, what's the purpose of the last template in your XSLT: <xsl:template match="@*|node()">? With or without it, the stylesheet works exactly the same.

Comment: That's the 'identity' template, that copies any node for which you don't have a specific match. There should be a difference, as without it you will loose the root 'div' element.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more straightforward  you may try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kId" match="seg/w" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/DIV">
        <div>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@id='fr']/seg"/>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="div/seg">
            <li>
                <xsl:for-each select="w" >
                    <w><xsl:value-of select="."/></w>
                    <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                    <w>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('kId',substring-after(@corresp, '#'))"/>
                    </w>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li><w>AA</w> : <w>BX</w><br/><w>BB</w> : <w>CX</w><br/><w>CC</w> : <w>AX</w><br/></li>
    <li><w>DD</w> : <w>AX</w><br/><w>EE</w> : <w>CX</w><br/></li>
    <li><w>FF</w> : <w>AX</w><br/><w>GG</w> : <w>CX</w><br/><w>HH</w> : <w>BX</w><br/></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, after a series of your answers I've grasped the idea of keys better.

Comment: Yet, your output does not match mine. That is, every value from 'fr' <div> is matched repeatedly with the values from the first <seg> of <div> whose @id equals 'en'...

Comment: So you do not get the output which I posted above? (Because this seems to look like the expected)

Comment: I get the exact output you posted but this is not the target output I posted. Your templates ignore the cross-references defined by the values of @corresp

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not look close enough. Seems the answer from Tim C is what you are looking for.